# javasript for adobe acrobat PDF

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a dropdown list in a PDF, that I want the text to change colour depending on the selected answer

If I only have 2 choices, I can make the code work just fine

Example
yes = blue
No = Red

But if I try and add a third text they all go one colour

yes = blue
No = Red
N/A

This statement works

var v = getField("Dropdown5").valueAsString;

if (v=="Yes") {event.target.textColor = color.blue;}

else {event.target.textColor = color.red;}

But not this one

var v = getField("Dropdown6").valueAsString;

if (v=="Yes") {event.target.textColor = color.blue;}

if (v=="No") {event.target.textColor = color.red;}

else {event.target.textColor = color.green;}

Comment: if (v=='yes'){ ... } `else` if (v=='no'){ ... } else { ... }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.